# Difference when declaring objects with class or interface c#

Tags: c#, class, interface

I was unable to find a convincing answer, what was exact difference between declaring object as class or interface.

What would be the difference between both the code below

```
ILogger log = new MyLogger(); //ILogger is an interface and MyLogger class implements ILogger
```

and

```
MyLogger log = new MyLogger();
```

Both would create the object of type `MyLogger` then what is difference between above two.

Comment: Read it http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-interfaces-what-are-they-and here is short explaination. But please do any research before asking questions.

Comment: I would say that basically line `ILogger log = new MyLogger();` expects log to be of type which implements the things from `ILogger` interface and line `MyLogger log = new MyLogger();` expects log to be of `MyLogger` type.

Answer (score 1):

No, difference if you think from perspective of Object creation but if you declare as

```
ILogger log = new MyLogger();
```

then you will be able to access only those functions, properties directly without adding `cast` which are declared in Interface `ILogger` but on other hand with declaration

```
MyLogger log = new MyLogger();
```

you will be able to access all the functions and properties of  class `MyLogger` as well as of interface `ILogger` as class implements the interface `ILogger`